# Disable All Form Elements with Radio Button

Tags: javascript

Trying to find a solution that allows me to enable ALL fields in a form if the first radio button (Feedback) is changed to "On" but the page must load with Feedback defaulting to "Off". All of the fields must load in the disabled state. If Feedback is changed to "on", other fields should become enabled. And then of course, if Off is selected, the fields become disabled again.

I've tried many bits and pieces of code, trying to patch together a single solution but I can't figure it out. Many of the solutions are based on very old versions of jQuery, and I'm using a current version. Not that jQuery is a requirement, pure JavaScript would be fine (if possible).

Grateful for any help. Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label>Feedback</label>
<input id="controlon" class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="feedback" value="on">
<label>On</label>
<input id="controloff" class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="feedback" value="off" checked>
<label>Off</label>

<hr />

<label>Name</label>
<input id="name" class="" type="text" name="text">

<label>Species</label>
<select id="species" class="" name="species">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>- Select -</option>
    <option value="1">Cat</option>
    <option value="1">Dog</option>
</select>

<label>Age</label>
<input id="kp" class="" type="radio" name="age" value="on">
<label>Kitten/Puppy</label>
<input id="adult" class="" type="radio" name="age" value="off" checked>
<label>Adult</label>

<label>Comments</label>
<textarea id="comments" class="" rows="4"></textarea>

<button id="send" class="">Send</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
    <label>Feedback</label>
    <input id="controlon" class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="feedback" value="on">
    <label>On</label>
    <input id="controloff" class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="feedback" value="off" checked>
    <label>Off</label>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="w3-container">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input id="name" class="" type="text" name="text" disabled>

    <label>Species</label>
    <select id="species" class="" name="species" disabled>
        <option value="0" disabled selected>- Select -</option>
        <option value="1">Cat</option>
        <option value="1">Dog</option>
    </select>

    <label>Age</label>
    <input id="kp" class="" type="radio" name="age" value="on" disabled checked>
    <label>Kitten/Puppy</label>
    <input id="adult" class="" type="radio" name="age" value="off" disabled>
    <label>Adult</label>

    <label>Comments</label>
    <textarea id="comments" class="" rows="4" disabled></textarea>

    <button id="send" class="" disabled>Send</button>
</div>

<script>
    $('input:radio[name="feedback"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val()=='on') {
            $('#name,#species,#kp,#adult,#comments,#send').attr('disabled', false);
        } 
        else if ($(this).val()=='off') {
            $('#name,#species,#kp,#adult,#comments,#send').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Man you're a life saver !!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to be more specific about exactly you want enabled or disabled.  Here's the general idea:

```
if (document.getElementById("controlon").checked === true) {
  document.getElementById('whatever').disabled = false;

 // or get multiple elements by whatever you want
}
```

For multiple fields you can do something like:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('whatever');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].disabled = false;
}
```

Detect change / jquery:

```
$( ".w3-radio" ).change(function() {
   if ($('#controlon').is(':checked')) {
     // apply the same class to everything you want enabled
     $('.whatever').prop("disabled", false);
   } else {
     $('.whatever').prop("disabled", true);;
   }
});
```

working example:

https://codepen.io/jfitzsimmons/pen/QRboYj?editors=1111

Comment: You're right, I modified the post to be more clear in this regard, I'll try your suggestion, thanks

Comment: @Kodara I'm still not 100% on what you'd like disabled.  I updated my answer with a suggestion on how to enable multiple fields by classname.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your suggestion by changing "whatever" to "name" in Line 2 and nothing happened, the console reports the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Comment: Just to be clear, when the page loads, I would like "every" form field disabled (except of course, the Feedback radio)

Comment: @Kodara You're going to need some sort of listener for when your radio buttons change.  Then you will need a conditional like I have posted.  Try to add some javascript and then ask your question when you get stuck.  Look into event listeners, onChange and different ways to getElements.

Comment: I've been stuck for 4 days, trying one apparent solution after another, thanks anyway

Comment: @Kodara I added what is has to be a close example of what you want.  Get a jsfiddle or codepen together and it will be easier for me to work and know what exactly you're going for.

Comment: @Kodara I updated my answer and have a decently working example.  You just need to add a similar class to all inputs you want disabled/enabled  https://codepen.io/jfitzsimmons/pen/QRboYj?editors=1111